# RuntimeError: can't start new thread, but works with sudo

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, sudo

```
from threading import Thread

def salut():
    print("sal")


th = Thread(target=salut, args=[])
th.start()
th.join()
```

So I have this code and running it by the following command:

```
python3 main.py
```

Will give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    th.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

But if I run it with sudo:

```
sudo python3 main.py
```

It works just as intended and prints sal.

Why is this the case? This happens on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS but on any other pc that I have which runs Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS it works without sudo.

Comment: What is the difference in setup between the this machine and others? What if you run this with `strace`? I'd suspect something like SELinux or similar things to possibly make a difference.

Comment: Looking at similars questions on StackOverflow seems to indicate that you have too many processes/threads already running on the machine. Could this be possible ?